# How i can retrieve MongoDB data inTextboxes through javadriver?

Tags: mongodb, textbox

How can I retrieve MongDB data and load in textboxes using javadriver?

I tried the following code to show data, but I want to get the data in textboxes:

```
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject();
doc.put("Name", v2);
doc.put("SID", n4);
doc.put("University", v4);
DBCursor Cur = coll.find(doc);   
System.out.println(Cur);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code fragment shows how to extract the individual fields of a document when you iterate over the results of a query. You could, if you wanted, take each field and put it in a textbox of a GUI.

The complete code sample is here: https://gist.github.com/3087822

```
private static void queryAndDisplayStudents(DBCollection students)
{
    // Get all students (no query criteria).
    DBCursor cursor = students.find();

    // Iterate over the students.
    while (cursor.hasNext()) 
    {
        // Display each student.

        DBObject student = cursor.next();

        // Get the individual fields of the student document.
        // These individual fields could, for example, 
        // be put in text fields of a GUI.
        String name = (String) student.get("Name");
        Number sid  = (Number) student.get("SID");
        String university = (String) student.get("University");

        // Given that we are not actually building a GUI, 
        // just display the fields on the command line.
        System.out.printf("Student name: %s, SID: %d, University: %s%n", 
                          name, sid, university);
    }        
}
```

Comment: What if the documents are nested like
   `"Name":{ "First Name":"bob","Second Name":"Lien"},
     "SID":10,"University":"INA"`
now how can `Name` document(nested ) will be showed on text boxes, the above code  you give is for simple documents and now i want to show data of nested or embedded document. I hope you understand my question.

Comment: plz help me with nested one ? if documents are nested how will we access nested documents in java ?